# setUserCredentials from Google data api is stuck

Tags: authentication, google-calendar-api

Well, since I am facing some issues with OAuth implementation, I decided to go back to normal method where users will input their login id and password and I will use them in my code to validate their google account to fetch calendar information. So when user enters login id and password, the page is getting stuck. When I check the code, **setUserCredentials** is the method where it is getting stuck. But when I enter my login id and password and debug on development site, it works fine. There is no problem when I debug. And importantly , the problem appears for first time only, once I debug the code and next time I try it without breakpoint, it works fine.

Does anyone know why **setUserCredentials** takes time or any way I can track why it is taking so time?

I have  asked the same question on Google data api forum, but nobody answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reverted back to old Google Data API version from 1.41 to 1.40 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What issues are you facing with the OAuth implementation?  Using client login can potentially cause accounts to be flagged as hijacked.

Comment: I have the questions related to Oauth earlier. Well my application is safe and asks for user details for once only.